# sum values depending on other column without pandas in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I tried to sum the point but I got an error about`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` .
After than I wrote `Change_Point = int(float(row[6]))` and I got `'int' object is not iterable`. I just want to sum the change point without pandas.

```
import csv
import json

with open('sample.csv','r') as file:
    rows = csv.reader(file,delimiter='|')
    next(rows, None)
    y = []
    orders = {}
    for row in rows:
        PointRec_ID = row[0]        
        Opeartion = row[1]        
        Member_ID = row[2]                
        Order_ID = row[3]        
        Point_Valid_Date = row[4]        
        Point_Invalid_Date = row[5]        
        Change_Point = row[6]  
        Accumulative_Point = row[7]       
        if not Order_ID in orders :
            orders[Order_ID] = {
                'PointRec_ID': PointRec_ID,
                'Opeartion': Opeartion,
                'Member_ID': Member_ID,
                'Order_ID': Order_ID,
                'Point_Valid_Date': Point_Valid_Date,
                'Point_Invalid_Date': Point_Invalid_Date,
                'Change_Point': sum(Change_Point),
                'Accumulative_Point': Accumulative_Point,                
            }
        order = orders[Order_ID]
    for Order_ID in orders:        
        y.append(orders[Order_ID])
print(json.dumps(y))
```

example csv:

```
PointRec_ID|Opeartion|Member_ID|Order_ID|Point_Valid_Date|Point_Invalid_Date|Change_Point|Accumulative_Point
20200819000001760|Point gain|00100224165|AD031SA12016866|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|639|934
20200819000001761|Point gain|00100224165|AD031SA12016866|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|0|934
20200819000001762|Point gain|00100224165|AD031SA12016866|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|1|935
20200819000001763|Point gain|00101206808|AD031SA12016867|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|89|90
20200819000001764|Point gain|00101206808|AD031SA12016867|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|699|789
20200819000001765|Point gain|00101206808|AD031SA12016867|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|0|789
20200819000001766|Point gain|00101206808|AD031SA12016867|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|1|790
20200819000001767|Point gain|00101206808|AD031SA12016867|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|0|790
20200819000001768|Point gain|00101206808|AD031SA12016867|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|1169|1959
```

expect result(If I output csv):

```
20200819000001762|Point gain|00100224165|AD031SA12016866|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|640|935
20200819000001768|Point gain|00101206808|AD031SA12016867|2020-08-23 16:00:00|2021-08-23 16:00:00|1958|1959
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That's because `Change_Point` is only one integer, for example `639` for the first row, and Python's `sum` function takes an iterable as an argument. It makes no sense to ask for `sum(639)` since it's only one integer, thus the error. What are you trying to do precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sum the values for existing items.

```
import csv
import json

with open('sample.csv','r') as file:
    rows = csv.reader(file,delimiter='|')
    y = [next(rows, None)]
    
    orders = {}
    for row in rows:
        PointRec_ID = row[0]        
        Opeartion = row[1]        
        Member_ID = row[2]                
        Order_ID = row[3]        
        Point_Valid_Date = row[4]        
        Point_Invalid_Date = row[5]        
        Change_Point = row[6]  
        Accumulative_Point = row[7] 
            
        if not Order_ID in orders :
            orders[Order_ID] = {
                'PointRec_ID': PointRec_ID,
                'Opeartion': Opeartion,
                'Member_ID': Member_ID,
                'Order_ID': Order_ID,
                'Point_Valid_Date': Point_Valid_Date,
                'Point_Invalid_Date': Point_Invalid_Date,
                'Change_Point': int(Change_Point),
                'Accumulative_Point': Accumulative_Point,                
            }
        else:
            orders[Order_ID]["Change_Point"] +=  int(Change_Point)
            
    for Order_ID in orders:        
        y.append(list(orders[Order_ID].values()))
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Change_Point inside the for loop to `Change_Point  = [int(row[6])] + [int(i[6]) for i in rows]`

```
import csv
import json

with open('sample.csv','r') as file:
    rows = csv.reader(file,delimiter='|')
    next(rows, None)
    y = []
    orders = {}
    for row in rows:
        PointRec_ID = row[0]        
        Opeartion = row[1]        
        Member_ID = row[2]                
        Order_ID = row[3]        
        Point_Valid_Date = row[4]        
        Point_Invalid_Date = row[5]        
        Change_Point = [int(row[6])] + [int(i[6]) for i in rows] # list of change
        #print(Change_Point)
        Accumulative_Point = row[7]       
        if not Order_ID in orders :
            orders[Order_ID] = {
                'PointRec_ID': PointRec_ID,
                'Opeartion': Opeartion,
                'Member_ID': Member_ID,
                'Order_ID': Order_ID,
                'Point_Valid_Date': Point_Valid_Date,
                'Point_Invalid_Date': Point_Invalid_Date,
                'Change_Point': sum(Change_Point),
                'Accumulative_Point': Accumulative_Point,                
           }
        order = orders[Order_ID]
    for Order_ID in orders:        
        y.append(orders[Order_ID])
print(json.dumps(y))
```

Output:

```
[{"PointRec_ID": "20200819000001760", "Opeartion": "Point gain", "Member_ID": "00100224165", "Order_ID": "AD031SA12016866", "Point_Valid_Date": "2020-08-23 16:00:00", "Point_Invalid_Date": "2021-08-23 16:00:00", "Change_Point": 2598, "Accumulative_Point": "934"}]
```